# Golang paralelism

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I've been recently reading a lot about parallelism and concurrency in Go, and I can't wrap my head around it. When I was reading [this article about concurrency and parallelism in Go](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html), I've came across this statement:

> We can see that the goroutines are truly running in parallel. Both
>   goroutines start running immediately and you can see them both
>   competing for standard out to display their results.

This statement is related to this program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    fmt.Println("Starting Go Routines")
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        for char := ‘a’; char < ‘a’+26; char++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        for number := 1; number < 27; number++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Waiting To Finish")
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("\nTerminating Program")
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Starting Go Routines
Waiting To Finish
a b 1 2 3 4 c d e f 5 g h 6 i 7 j 8 k 9 10 11 12 l m n o p q 13 r s 14
t 15 u v 16 w 17 x y 18 z 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
Terminating Program
```

So, does that means that in the runtime 2 cycles from the goroutines executing at the same time (so at this point we can call Go parallel language) or scheduler just switches context between those two threads (probably on fmt.Printf call) and executing only one cycle at one (concurrency, not true parallelism, as the author mentioned in the quote above)?

I'm confused.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. The interesting thing about it that it simply does not matter and you should not care. This is concurrency. Things are done concurrently and that is all there is to say. Things happen independently and simultaneous. Nothing to worry here. What happens on the physical hardware level: You should not care. If you have just one core: Nothing ever will happen "in parallel". If you have more cores: Some things might or might not happe nin parallel. The thing about concurrent execution is that you do not need to care about physical parallelism.

Comment: @Volker I def agree in general, but what about if you're trying to optimize/benchmark a CPU bound operation? I guess if there are configurable goroutine pool sizes load testing and choosing the right config sizes are still agnostic to OS because the data will eventually settle on the correct configuration? ie if we're doing hashing concurrently, and initially setting a pool size/# concurrent hashes to a large number, we'll eventually settle on something closer to the number of cores available?

Comment: @dm03514 if you have this sort of problem you know what you are doing and how to arrange data to keep your cores busy and your memory pipelines full. Basically Go has _no_ tunable parts, it is not Java. You limit goroutines with GOMAXPROCS and garbage collection with GOGC. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the function that prints a-z and 1-27 both start at the same time and you are waiting till both the go routines end. While having several go routines, your idea must be concurrent but if your hardware supports they might run parallel.

[Concurreny is not parallelism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso&t=1411s)

Also context switches are heavy so most of the times they are most probably not done. Go routines are really light and hundreds of them can be running at the same time.

Comment: I've already watched that video by Rob Pike. So okay, they are starting at the same time, but my question was - did they executing at the same time? I mean like having 2 threads with goroutines that are running parallel

Comment: If your hardware is capable then they might be executing at the same instant of time. Else both the goroutines will be running at the same time.

Comment: So does that means, that we can call golang parallel language?

Comment: NO. Calling it parallel language cannot be generalized. Parallelism is just a manifestation of concurrency.

Comment: @Src Whether you can call Go a "parallel language" depends on your definition of "parallel language". You can call it a "low level" and "high level" and "green-yellow" and "parallel" or "sequential". But this name calling does not change anything and is not helpful. So why bother.

Comment: @Volker I'm just trying to wrap my head around that, because almost everybody saying that golang can't execute two different goroutines at once, scheduler will have to switch between the task, when one of them will be blocked.. So i'm trying to understand that, because on the other side, there are articles (like i provided in the question) saying that if GOMAXPROCS will be equal to > 1, and you'll have more that 1 CPU - things will be executing at the same time. This confuses me.

Comment: If you are using a language like c, c++ where there is no option to run codes concurrently you&#39;ll have to worry about using threads, openmp and stuff. In Go you have go routines which asks developer not to think about any of this and just code the design he wants and leave concurrency / parallelism (whatever u may call ) to the language

Comment: @Src "because almost everybody saying that golang can't execute two different goroutines at once" nobody says this because this is 100% wrong. Go will happily execute up to the number of available cores goroutines in parallel. The number of available cores is limited by, well the number of cores you actually have and second by GOMAXPROCS. Forget about all this now and forever. GOMAXPROCS _was_ a thing in 2015. It is nomore.

Comment: @Volker so i'm loosing the point.. if it can execute things in parallel "up to a number of available cores" it's parallelism. Or we just call it concurrent language, because it is might not always be the case?

Comment: @Src There is _no_ point in this discussion. Nobody is interested in a discussion whether Go should be called a "parallel" or a "concurrent" language. The language constructs allow the construction of concurrent programs. These concurrent programs may or may not executed in parallel and this makes no difference. Assigning labels like "concurrent" or "parallel" or "green" or whatever is useless linguistic/taxonomical effort.

Comment: @Volker I'm not interested in giving labels to the language either, but i was just curios about how it's working under the hood.

Comment: @Src Go for sure is _NOT_ a parallel programming language as you _cannot_ force two statements to be executed "in parallel". But of corse do things happen in parallel if you execute a Go program. Let's just stop this naming thing.

Comment: @Src Then it is simple. All cores up to GOMAXPROCS are used if there is work to be done. Dead simple.

Comment: @Volker Great. So we can assume, that if we'll have 4 available cores, and there are 4 different goroutines, they will be executed simultaneously?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182266/discussion-between-volker-and-src).